# ng-if does not update in directive scope

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to remove a DOM element manipulating `ng-if` from a directive.

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('time', '$http', [function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,           
        link: function(scope, element) {
            window.alert(scope.element) // true
            scope.element = false
        }
   }
}]);
```

HTML ADDED

```
<div class= 'container'>
<div time ng-model = 'datescope' ng-if="datescopeValue">{{date}}</div>
<form role='form' ng-if='element'>
        <div class='form-group'>    
            <input ng-model='name' class= 'form-control' placeholder= 'username'/>
            <input ng-model='contents' class= 'form-control' placeholder= 'title'/>

            <button ng-click= "addComment(name, contents)" class='btn btn-default'>button
            </button>

        </div>
</form>
```

Even if I set `ng-if = 'element'` to be false, the element does not get removed from DOM dynamically. Why does this happen?

Comment: Is your `time` directive on the same element as `ng-if`? If so, it could be a priority issue

Comment: It is not on the same element :(

Comment: Where you put ng-if, can you post your `html` also ?

Comment: I somehow doubt the scope of the directive. Could you probably try having the same "sope.element" on the parent, and then give it a try?

Comment: Show the template for this directive. Maybe your template creates additional child scopes, and so your primitive boolean variable (`scope.element`) is shadowed in the child scopes.